# Sort on specific columns, output only one of those identical but having the highest number in another column

Tags: sorting, duplicates, uniq

I have records like these:

```
1 4 6 4 2 4 8
2 3 5 4 6 7 1
5 4 6 4 3 8 4
1 4 6 4 5 7 1
5 7 3 3 3 6 3
6 7 3 3 4 8 4
```

I want to sort them on columns 2,3,4, and 6 and keep just one of those identical in column 2,3,4 and having the biggest number in column 6 such as:

```
1 4 6 4 5 7 1
2 3 5 4 6 7 1
5 4 6 4 3 8 4
5 7 3 3 3 6 3
6 7 3 3 4 8 4
```

I have tried all kinds of combinations between sort and uniq but everything fails because uniq cannot be applied onto a specific column. The only thing I came up with is to change the order of the columns as to first sort as above then move records 2,3,and 4 to the end and then run uniq with -w as to focus only on the last 3 records. This seems quite inefficient to me.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Sorry, I am new and I just noticed that the records are not being displayed as they should be! They should be in blocks of 7 like: 1 4 6 4 2 4 8/ 2 3 5 4 6 7 1 / 5 4 6 4 3 8 4 / etc

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with two passes of `sort`(assuming in the first place I understand your requirement correctly, seeing that the desired data snippet posted above does not match your description of it) . The first pass sorts by field 2 through 4 ascending and field 6 descending, the second pass sorts on fields 2 through 4 only but passing in the "stable sort" and unique flags in addition to pick out those rows for each combination of fields 2-4 that have the highest value from field 6

```
sort -k2,4n -k6,6nr  file.txt | sort -k2,4n -s -u
2 3 5 4 6 7 1
5 4 6 4 3 8 4
6 7 3 3 4 8 4
```